# Book Recommendation Please! [Casella Berger] Statistical Inference

Tags: probability, statistics, reference-request

I would appreciate your 2 cent on book recommendation.
I have basic exposure to probability theory back in college (e.g. calc, stats, probability undergrad level) but haven't dealt with them for a while.

I am seeking that perfect book which could aid my reading on Casella Berger's **Statistical Inference**. An analogous example in Linear Algebra is, before delving into graduate level linear algebra, I read Axler's **Linear Algebra Done Right**, and this helped me tremendously.

A seasoned person, please help!
Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could look at Hogg, Mckean and Craig's Introduction to Mathematical Statistics.

But Casella and Berger's Statistical Inference is suitable as a first text for both undergrads and graduate students with basic mathematical maturity.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will take a look into it!

Comment: I should add that Casella and Berger is probably too easy if you are already familiar with measure theory, despite its reputation as a "graduate level" textbook -- it is only really suitable for people without measure-theoretic knowledge.

Comment: It is definitely one of those graduate level books which is suitable for people who aren't graduate students. But even for people who know measure theory, it may be useful as a supplement to something like Shao's Mathematical Statistics (which I think is my favorite intro text).